# Typescript, conditional type based on the value of a string literal type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm a little stuck on how to define a conditional type for typescript based on a predefined string literal

**This is a mockup / example to help explain** For a little background, a user is supposed to label data from images, currently there are only 2 types of things to label (for this example lets say its `pedestrians` and `vehicles`) potentially more in the future.

In my Redux store I am storing data from an API request (request gets a new set of data to label based on one of these types). The issue is the data that i get is in different formats for the two types of things to label aka array of frames or object with values that are frame arrays.

```
type ILabelingTypes = "pedestrians" | "vehicles"
```

A frame would look like this

```
interface IFrame {
    url: string
    orientation: number
    // anything else related to a frame
}
```

The api requests would be `/labeling/vehicles/new` with an example response

```
{
    // meta info about the labeling session
    frames: IFrame[]
}
```

or `/labeling/pedestrians/new` with an example response

```
{
    // meta info about the labeling session
    frames: Map<string, IFrame[]>
}
```

The issue I'm having now is when I define my store interface, how do i correctly type the `frames` key so that I don't have to check everywhere i go to use it what type of data it is?

```
interface ILabelingStore {
    labelingType: ILabelingTypes
    frames: // what do i put here?
}
```

Meaning when i go to render or use this data I'd like to simply call methods that i know exist depending on the `labelingType` defined in the store

---

For the React component side, when i go to render the frames I build a queue of frames to complete, so i need to know what type the data is in the respective component **(This is what i would like to do instead of having to check the type of frames)**

```
// pedestrians component
componentDidMount() {
    Object.entries(this.props.frames).forEach( (key, val) => this.queue.concat(val))
}

// vehicles component
componentDidMount() {
    this.queue.concat(this.props.frames)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a discriminated union:

```
type ILabelingStore = ({
        labelingType: "vehicles",
        frames: IFrame[]
    } | {
        labelingType: "pedestrians",
        frames: { [key: string]: IFrame[] }
    });
```

[Demo](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IFrame%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20url%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20orientation%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20anything%20else%20related%20to%20a%20frame%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ILabelingTypes%20%3D%20%22pedestrians%22%20%7C%20%22vehicles%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ILabelingStore%20%3D%20(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20labelingType%3A%20%22vehicles%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20frames%3A%20IFrame%5B%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%7C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20labelingType%3A%20%22pedestrians%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20frames%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20IFrame%5B%5D%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20a%3A%20ILabelingStore%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20labelingType%3A%20%22pedestrians%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20frames%3A%20%7B%20a%3A%20%5B%5D%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0Aconst%20b%3A%20ILabelingStore%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20labelingType%3A%20%22vehicles%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20frames%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! this looks like what i need but I have some compiler errors in my redux store (return value not matching). after fixing those issues if this solves my problem i'll accept it! :)

Comment: im having an issue assigning a string literal type to the discriminated union. mind taking a look? https://preview.tinyurl.com/y8ougmxv

Comment: The compiler can't prove that `payload` is the same value as your object, so it gives you an error because it's afraid that the properties no longer match.

Comment: So how would I go about proving that? i was already specifying `payload` is one of those values. Do i need to make a type guard? I tried type guard with no luck :/

Comment: I think you'd need to make your lambda generic so that you can specify which `ILabelingTypes` it is in the type system.  It would then only accept whichever params matches its type parameter.

Comment: Im going to go ahead and accept this. I went about it a different way since the union type was getting messy for my use case. But i think this is a good answer for others looking for types based off of a particular string value :)